# conditionally replace grouped values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Let's say i have the df below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],'category' : ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'],'price':[1,2,3,10,2,3,4,20,1,10,1,4]})
print(df)
     id    category value
0    1        A      1
1    1        A      2
2    1        A      3
3    1        A     10
4    2        B      2
5    2        B      3
6    2        B      4
7    2        B     20
8    3        C      1
9    3        C     10
10   3        C      1
11   3        C      4
```

For values('price') of the same id and category, I want to replace them with the mean of the rest values when they don't satisfy a condition. For instance, for the id 1 and category A, I would like to replace the 10 with the mean of the other three values(1,2,3). I have tried many things, but nothing seems to work. Any suggestion on how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Please be explicit and exhaustive. What are exactly the conditions? Also, please provide the expected output.

Comment: Thanks. So the condition is if a value is 2 times larger/ lower than the mean of the other values, replace it with the mean of those values. the expected output is to replace the 'outliers' of each group of those 4 values with the mean of that specific group.

Comment: Larger than the mean of the other values (tricky to do) or the mean of the group?

Comment: First case. I want to check if there is some type of measurement error for each group and replace the outliers with a more sensible value.

Comment: I was talking about the condition to detect outliers. Is it fine is it detects based on the mean of the group and then replaces with the mean of the non-outliers? The problem with the condition on the mean of the non-outliers is that you basically need to know the solution before you solve it ;)

Comment: I am just trying to figure it out myself too. If it's not doable, then how about detect the outlier and then replace it with the median of all four values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that detects outliers based on the mean of the group and then replaces them with the mean of the non outliers:

```
means = df.groupby(['id', 'category'])['price'].transform('mean')
df['new_price'] = df['price'].where(~(df['price'].gt(2*means)|df['price'].lt(0.5*means)), float('nan'))
df['new_price'] = df['new_price'].where(~df['new_price'].isna(), df.groupby(['id', 'category'])['new_price'].transform('mean'))

# for debugging only
df['outlier'] = df['price'].where(~(df['price'].gt(2*means)|df['price'].lt(0.5*means)), float('nan')).isna()
```

output:

```
    id category  price  new_price  outlier
0    1        A      1        2.5     True
1    1        A      2        2.0    False
2    1        A      3        3.0    False
3    1        A     10        2.5     True
4    2        B      2        4.0     True
5    2        B      3        4.0     True
6    2        B      4        4.0    False
7    2        B     20        4.0     True
8    3        C      1        4.0     True
9    3        C     10        4.0     True
10   3        C      1        4.0     True
11   3        C      4        4.0    False
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the mean of all  values < max value of a group. You can iterate it with tuples based on your conditions:

```
df.loc[(df['category'] == 'A')&(df['id'] == 1), ['price']].loc[df.loc[(df['category'] == 'A')&(df['id'] == 1), ['price']].values < df.loc[(df['category'] == 'A')&(df['id'] == 1), ['price']].values.max(), 'price'].mean()
```